# What is a good history of logic book that covers all logic?

Tags: logic, history-of-logic

Including inductive, formal and mathematical. I find them separated a lot and I don't know if I have the ability to sit through all the Handbook of the History of Logic series.

Comment: Inductive logic is hardly included into usual History of Logic books. See Kneale & Kneale , [The Development of Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=FtXAwgy1w9cC&printsec=frontcover) and Leila Haaparanta (editor), [The Development of Modern Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=0jXavKsArnIC&pg=PA1).

Comment: Formal and mathematical are the same subject. Inductive/informal are a different subject using an older sense of "logic", it is not very cohesive to lump them together. But you can try [The History of Philosophical and Formal Logic: From Aristotle to Tarski by Malpass-Marfori](https://books.google.com/books?id=hJPQDgAAQBAJ&source=gbs_navlinks_s).

Comment: Well, "all of logic" is **hugely** broad. I think looking for a single book will ultimately be futile - there's just too much to say, and given the variety it's actually better to *avoid* a single perspective: even if we ignore issues of bias, there's the simple fact that one would want each topic to be covered by an expert in said topic, and I'd be amazed if a universal expert existed. I think, daunting though it may be, the HHL series is worth the effort if you really want to know it "all." (You can pick-and-choose from the essays, after all, so it's not *really* thousands of pages to read.)

Comment: Do you think that's more of an issue for logic than philosophy?